# Number input with 0.01 steps gives undefined for certain values in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With a input of that type in angularjs (1.6.1) gives `undefined` for values between `9.03` to `9.05` inclusively. The problem reproduces with other values, among others `9.62`, `9.63`, `17.31`.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" data-ng-model="$ctrl.numericValue" />
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td1dnkcL/1/) reproduces the problem. Just click up in the numeric input.

Tested on firefox and chromium under linux mint 18.

It seems linked to the `"step"` attribute. If it is set to `"0.001"` there's no problem. But I threat money in this application, so 2 decimal is needed.

Note : if value is initially set to `9.03` via `data-numeric-value`, it is *not* `undefined`.

Any workaround for this bug ?

**edit**

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td1dnkcL/3/) to show behavior whit `step="0.01"` versus `step="0.001"`

**edit 2**
I made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pUHASXPbPW0F4DXAOChD?p=preview) while filling the bug report, to find that the bug is corrected in the "snapshot" version, witch is 1.6.2. But this version is not available for download via the angularjs site for the moment.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15257

Comment: @eoascarello : this bug was for step=0.1 and is closed. Seems mine is a "new" one...

Comment: Log a bug with them, just was showing they had the same type of issues. When you manually check the value of the input, the value is there so it is something with how they are mapping the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Angular. Using Angular 1.6.0, the same issue happens. If you use Angular 1.5.9, it seems to work fine. Something between those two versions has caused this issue and it has not been found or resolved in 1.6.1 yet.

So the best course of action is to raise a bug with the Angular team.

A short term solution for your own project would be to roll back to Angular 1.5.9 if possible.

I've tested it on Windows 7 on both Firefox and Chrome to get these results.

Comment: I made a plunkr while filling the bug report, to find that the bug is corrected in the "snapshot" version, witch is 1.6.2. But this version is not available for download via the angularjs site.

Answer (score 0):

I recon it's a weird glitch due to JavaScript's floating point precision. I suggest you reconfigure your input to have a different step (preferrably with integers meaning a step of 1) then use the fetched value divided by 100.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a nice solution, but you can use jquery.
You have to include jquery before angular:

```
 <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

assign an id to the input field

```
<input id="numericValue1" type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="$ctrl.numericValue1" />
```

and, then, use the id to get the value

```
ctrl.showValue1 = function(){
    return "value 1 is " + $('#numericValue1').val() + " and its type is " + typeof ctrl.numericValue1;
  };
```

I hope this working fine!